# Background image is not showing on page while showing in Developer Tool

Tags: css

I have used background image in stylesheet but not showing in page while showing me on developer tool or copy past url on url its work.
here is code

```
.page-footer {
    background: url(https://priyachaudhary.com/pub/media/footer/footer-priya);
    position: relative;
    /* background: #f8f8f8; */
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
```

Comment: Are you getting a white background?

Comment: no;nothing is show

Comment: `}` is missing also

Comment: what element is this class on, a div? if it's an inline element, it will not render anything because the width will be 0. You should give the .page-footer a width if it's not a block level element (like a span). If you show us your html as well (only the relevant part) we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer{
  background: url(https://priyachaudhary.com/pub/media/footer/footer-priya);
  width: 100%;
  height: 1205px;

  position: relative;
  /* background: #f8f8f8; */
  padding: 40px 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
 fooot
</footer>
```

The origin image has a long white space.

and you should type `width` and `height`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, The image is `1559px x 1205px`and the element is just `100% x 98px`, So you see the top part which is white.

So you need either to customize that image using a photo editor, Or increase the element height:

```
.page-footer {
    background: url(https://priyachaudhary.com/pub/media/footer/footer-priya);
    position: relative;
    /* background: #f8f8f8; */
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
    height: 1200px
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sva7rkcp/4/

Comment: @Abu, Scroll down to see the flowers